# Jenkins alerts when a remote cron job fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to setup a Jenkins server to monitor a bunch of cron jobs. I will launch most of them using the Jenkins freestyle project however some of the cron jobs will be remote so they will be communicating back as external jobs. How can I get warnings when those external jobs fail? and can I set the schedule they should be on so I can get warnings even when they don't run?

Thanks.

Comment: how do you trigger or plan to trigger the cron jobs from jenkins ?

Comment: The tasks on the jenkins box I could easily trigger using the freestyle project using the scheduler. The remote ones I'll use cron and the external jobs command line `java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/external-job-monitor/java/jenkins-core-*.jar "external-build-test" ls -l`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding and to answer your latter question, you can setup an overall cron scheduler in your Jenkins monitoring job in such a way it runs exactly during the time you expect the remote cron to execute . Say ur remote job executes at 1 pm every day u can configure your Jenkins monitor cron to kick off a build at 12.45 pm or 1 pm based on ur needs.

A solution to your first question could be to have a wrapper script execute the remote invocation of jobs so tht u can monitor the return value of tht remote invocation.

Like if you have an ant script invoke the Java command remotely, it will return a non zero if the Java command failed execution and the ant script will also fail and so your Jenkins job executing the ant script will fail and u will be notified about it.

I can help you with further specific steps if you did not follow me